# Should magical-theory be combined with magic?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

I was going through and adding tag wikis for some of the more used tags that don't have wikis and came across the [magical-theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-theory) tag - it contains 21 questions that all bar one deal with HP (the odd man out is closed).  When I tried to write a tag wiki for this, I found it very difficult to write one that would not basically apply to the [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) tag as well.

While I understand how that tag is currently being used that served as a bit of a red flag that it may be an artificial split from the [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) tag.  Especially given, by definition, questions on the theory of magic are questions dealing with magic.  Should [magical-theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-theory) be converted into a synonym of [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it should be.

As I mentioned in chat, magic is an action, an occurance. *Alohomora* opens doors and locks. *Wingardium Leviosa* causes items to rise and float. *Avada Kedavra* kills someone.

On the other hand, Gamp's Elemental Law of Transfiguration are a set of five rules of objects you cannot create by magic via Transfiguration -- why not? Why can't food be created out of thin air? There's discussion there, not to mention what might the other four items that cannot be conjured be. How does the Philosopher's Stone work? Why can't half-humans engage in certain types of magic? To me, these are examples of theory while the former are examples of straight up magic.

And I do say this with respect so please know I'm not trying to be snarky, but perhaps if you cannot write this particular wiki tag, another person might have better luck if they gave it a go.

My two cents :)

Comment: So? These are questions about magic. What makes them different from other questions about the rules of magic that have the tag [tag:magic]?

Comment: Sounds like you're saying [tag:magic] is analogous to [tag:technology].  Then [tag:magic-theory] is similar to [tag:science].  Each is the application of the other.

Comment: Or as Donald.McLean pointed out in chat, like the relationship between Theoretical Computer Science, and the programming SE's.

Comment: @GabeWillard No, the distinction between [cstheory.se] and [so] is not theory vs practice. It's science vs engineering. There are no magic engineering questions on the site (that would be something like “how do I turn someone into a newt?”).

Comment: Given the attention on the tag, I'm making it a condition for it to stay: you (collective) must provide a tag wiki. The tag wiki must explain clearly which questions should have that tag. “Questions about the theory of magic” is evidently not enough since we have different ideas as to which questions should have the tag. For example, I don't see what distinguishes questions like “How does the Philosopher's Stone?” from “What does *Avada Kedavra* do?” — they're both about magic.

Comment: @Gilles - the difference is between  “What does Avada Kedavra do?" and "Why can't you block the 3 Unforgivable curses". I'll let someone more literate than me to try and explain that in plain English.

Comment: The CS difference is "What's the O(N) speed of bubble sort" vs. "Why can there be no generic sort algorithm faster than O(N*logN)

Comment: To take another tack, "magic" are questions that mention existance of magic, but NOT delve into why/how specific magic works in a specific way in a framework of the Universe. "What is the effect of a specific spell" is the engineering equivalent"

Comment: @DVK Regarding your CS example: we'd use the same tags for the two. Regarding your other tack: I see where you're heading, but it's a very thin distinction, it doesn't seem useful to me. Would you subscribe to one tag and not the other? Would having distinct tags help searches?

Comment: @Gilles - I put "magical-theory" tag VERY high on my priority list (and don't pay any attention to magic tag). If there's a Q with such tag (especially in Harry Potter) it will be the very first one I will attempt to research and answer and the first one I will read

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, I do not see a difference in use between [magical-theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-theory) and [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic). The tag wiki for [magical-theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-theory) specifies that it is “used for questions about the rules of how magic is treated within a specific work or works”; many [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) questions have this characteristic.

I or another moderator will set up a synonym in a few days, barring motivated opposition. (Remind us if we forget.)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using the tag wiki excerpt into account - that's what I just wrote so it's not exactly an independant analysis. :)